# Positioning the input form in the middle using margin: 0 auto not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position the `input form` in the middle of form container using `margin: 0 auto;`, but not working.

I selected the `div` container and apply this:

```
.group {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: Royalblue; /*#f0f0f0;*/
  margin: 0px;
}

form {
  position: relative;  
  top: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 340px; 
  border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
  background: royalblue;   
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

/* Main EFFECT ================================ */


input {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;   
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border: 0; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;                     
  height: 25px; 
  width: 180px;
  outline: 0; 
  z-index: 1; 
  color: black;
}

label {
    display: block;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 1; 
  color: white; 
  transition: top .5s ease, font-size .5s ease; 
}

.group {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}

/*
label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;            
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 23px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: beige;
  transition: transform .7s;   
  transform: scale3d(1, 0.1, 1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
*/



/*
input:focus + label::after {
  top: 5px;  
  transform: scale3d(1, 1.2, 1);
  transition-timing-function: linear;
    
}


input:focus + label > span {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
*/
```

```html
<body>  

        <form>

       
                  <div class="group">
                     
                      <input class="input1" type="email" id="email" required /> 
                     
                      <label class="label1" for="email">
                          <span class="sp1">Email</span>
                      </label>
                 
                  </div>
     
         </form>
      
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: Royalblue; /*#f0f0f0;*/
  margin: 0px;
}

form {
  position: relative;  
  top: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 340px; 
  border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
  background: royalblue;   
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

/* Main EFFECT ================================ */


input {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;   
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border: 0; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;                     
  height: 25px; 
  width: 180px;
  outline: 0; 
  z-index: 1; 
  color: black;
}

label {
    display: block;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 1; 
  color: white; 
  transition: top .5s ease, font-size .5s ease; 
}

.group {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: max-content;
}

/*
label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;            
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 23px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: beige;
  transition: transform .7s;   
  transform: scale3d(1, 0.1, 1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
*/



/*
input:focus + label::after {
  top: 5px;  
  transform: scale3d(1, 1.2, 1);
  transition-timing-function: linear;
    
}


input:focus + label > span {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
*/
```

```html
<body>  

        <form>

       
                  <div class="group">
                     
                      <input class="input1" type="email" id="email" required /> 
                     
                      <label class="label1" for="email">
                          <span class="sp1">Email</span>
                      </label>
                 
                  </div>
     
         </form>
      
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

without width browser can not calculate how much margins it will put to left/right
you can see here in your case decrease width

http://prntscr.com/kvqscq

Comment: without width browser can not calculate how much margins it will put to left/right
you can see here in your case decrease width http://prntscr.com/kvqscq

Answer (score 1):

Give your .group class below css, and you're all set...

```
.group {
    width: max-content;
}
```

Now label will also move into center...

Comment: only the border-bottom: 1px solid white; is moving to center. I also want the label.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.sp1{
  left : 70px;
}
```